# Can Resorcerer work in Snow Leopard in VMWare Fusion 6?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, vmware, virtualization

Since Resorcerer (2.4.1) won't work at all in 10.7 and later, I tried it in a virtual machine running Snow Leopard Server 10.6.8 in VMWare Fusion 6.0.6.  But when I select a resource and click the Hex button, nothing happens. No error message, nothing in the Console log.  I tried nuking the Resorcerer preference file and increasing the RAM assigned to the VM.  Is there any way to get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Since Apple discourages the use of resource forks in new Mac OS X applications and prefers the application bundles instead, I doubt you will find that much "classical" resource forks anymore.

If you still need a similar app try [Rezilla](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rezilla/) instead. It works natively at least in 10.7-10.9.

Comment: I didn't say I was using resource forks.  Resources can live in a data fork inside a bundle.  But Rezilla does look useful, thanks for that.